# How to add metadata to my SPL token with multisign

Tags: spl-token, metadata, authority

I have a problem with a token created in early 2022.
I can't add metadata!
the mint account is multisign and I can't use metaplex to upload metadata file.

I thought I could to change authorize  owner without multisign, with "spl-token authorize"... but it return me an error.
is it the right strategy?
any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide information about the error you're seeing in `spl-token authorize`?

Comment: Edit: this is the correct strategy by the way -- I don't think metaplex supports spl-token multisigs as authorities, so you'll have to change the mint authority to a single key to create the metadata

Comment: yes... 
spl-token authorize "accountToken" owner "newSingleAccountToken" --multisig-signer key1.json --multisig-signer key2.json ....

Error: "Error: attempting to change the `owner` of an associated token account"

Comment: I tried too 

spl-token authorize "accountToken" owner "newSingleAccountToken"   --authority "multisignaccount "--multisig-signer key1.json --multisig-signer key2.json ....